# Angular component inside material context menu is not emitting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the cdk context menu from Angular Material but I'm not able to make it work properly when using a component for the menu itself. The @Input binding workis fine, but the @Output never emits (or the method I pass is never invoked).

I have the following template:

```html
<span
  class="tag-item"
  [ngClass]="tag.userTagCategory"
  (click)="displayTagInfo(tag)"
  [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"
  [cdkContextMenuTriggerData]="{ tag }"
>   
  {{ tag.name }}
  <span class="tag-weight">({{ tag.weight }})</span>
</span>

<ng-template #contextMenu let-item="tag">
  <app-user-item-context-menu
    [item]="{ id: item.id, selectedCategory: item.userTagCategory }"
    (setUserItem)="onSetUserTag($event.id, $event.selectedCategory)" // Issue here
  />
</ng-template>
```

And the following standalone component:

```js
export class UserItemContextMenuComponent {
  @Input()
  public item: UserItem | undefined;

  @Output()
  public setUserItem = new EventEmitter<UserItem>();

  protected onSetUserItem(id: string, selectedCategory?: UserCategory): void {
    this.setUserItem.emit({ id, selectedCategory });
  }
}
```

I tried to pass the method via the template, like this:
`[cdkContextMenuTriggerData]="{ tag, set: onSetUserTag }"`

```html
<ng-template #contextMenu let-item="tag" let-set="set">
  <app-user-item-context-menu
    [item]="{ id: item.id, selectedCategory: item.userTagCategory }"
    (setUserItem)="set($event)"
  />
</ng-template>
```

But it is also not working. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to accomplish the same kind of thing, I came up with a different approach, moving the trigger inside the context menu itself, and using content projection to display the item itself:

Context menu component:

```html
<span [cdkContextMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"> // No need for context data anymore
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
// context menu here
```

And use it like this:

```html
<app-user-item-context-menu [item]="tag" (setUserItem)="onSetUserTag($event)">
  <span class="tag-item" [ngClass]="tag.userTagCategory" (click)="displayTagInfo(tag)">
    {{ tag.name }}
    <span class="tag-weight">({{ tag.weight }})</span>
  </span>
</app-user-item-context-menu>
```